# Calculating which two points are the closest together given a series of points.

Tags: geometry, 3d

I'm in a position where I need to calculate the distance between two points to determine which is the closest point. Now, the proper formula to do this is:

$$distance = \sqrt{(x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 + (z2-z1)^2}$$

That's all well and good, but it's rather slow to calculate. I don't need to know the distance, just that the calculated distance is the shortest. So, thinking about how to do this, if I throw away the powering and square root, would I be able to determine which distance is the shortest by comparing the results, even though it would most certainly not give an accurate distance?

Comment: You can remove the square root but not the powers. If you remove the powers you may get cancellation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the square root -- just compare squared distances, rather than actual distances.

The multiplications will take very little time compared to the square root, but you can avoid some of those, too.

Suppose the current minimum distance is $d$, and suppose we're checking the point $P_i = (x_i, y_i, z_i)$ to see if it gives us a smaller distance to the base point $P_0 = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$. If $|x_i-x_0|$ is larger than $d$, then we know immediately that the distance from $P_i$ to $P_0$ is greater than $d$, so there's no sense in doing any further calculations. You can check $|y_i-y_0|$  and $|z_i-z_0|$ similarly.

Comment: I totally agree with your answer. However, from a computational point of view, the tests could be much more expensive than the straight computation of the squared distance.

Comment: Yes, you might be right. Depends what hardware, language, compiler etc. the OP is using. We have no way of knowing that, we only know that she wants to reduce multiplications. As you say, this might not be the right thing to do, but it's what she asked about.